# Does there exist an oracle $A$ such that $(P^{\#P})^{A} \neq PSPACE^{A}$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, oracles, relativization, pspace

**Background**

> We know that $P^{\#P} \subseteq PSPACE$.
>
> In addition, we known from
>   [Toda's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toda%27s_theorem) that $PH \subseteq P^{\#P}$.
>
> For more background on $\#P$, see here:
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P

**Question**

> Does there exist an oracle $A$ such that $(P^{\#P})^{A} \neq PSPACE^{A}$?

Comment: I would guess that for the first part, setting $A=\textrm{PSPACE}$ should be enough, right? Isn't it true that $\textrm{PSPACE}^{\textrm{PSPACE}} = \textrm{PSPACE}$?

Comment: @MichaelLampis Yep, if you count the space on the query tape, then that sound right to me!  :)

Comment: Great, thank you very much for pointing that out!  I modified the question removing the easier part about finding an oracle where they are equal.  :)

Comment: There is an oracle separating PP from PSPACE: Jacobo Toran, A combinatorial technique for separating counting complexity classes, ICALP 1989. The best result for P^PP that I know is a conditional result by Heribert Vollmer: Relating polynomial time to constant depth. TCS, 207: 159-170, 1998.

Comment: @MarkusBläser Thank you very much!  I really appreciate your help.  I will have to take a look at their papers.  :)

Comment: I took a look at the latter paper.  It seems that it contains a lot of neat related results as well.  :)

Comment: @MarkusBläser I think you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On popular request, here is my comment as an answer:

There is an oracle separating $\mathrm{PP}$ from $\mathrm{PSPACE}$: Jacobo Toran, A combinatorial technique for separating counting complexity classes, ICALP 1989. The best result for $\mathrm{P}^\mathrm{PP}$ that I know is a conditional result by Heribert Vollmer: Relating polynomial time to constant depth. TCS, 207: 159-170, 1998.

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, is it known that $P^{PP} = P^{\#P}$?

Comment: It seems straight forward that $P^{PP} \subseteq P^{\#P}$, but the other direction seems a little tricky.  You do some sort of binary search to compute the number of solutions to a verifier?

Comment: Yep, complexity zoo says that they are equal.  Also, I think I remember proving this in a complexity theory course a few years ago as an exercise.  :)

Comment: Complexity zoo also says that my main question is an open problem.  Sorry, I didn't realize that.  I thought maybe someone out there had solved it.